# Is there a way to share (hi-res) graphics in a Universal app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, interface-builder

I have an iPhone 4 app with both standard and hi-res graphics, e.g.:

```
icon-gun.png
icon-gun@2x.png
```

Now I want to do a iPad version, the size of `icon-gun@2x.png` will be good for the iPad version of my app. However, Interface Builder does not show `icon-gun@2x.png` as a selectable item in the Image View list box.

Is there a way I can re-use the `@2x` PNGs without copying and renaming? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set the image programmatically, I don't think there's a way to do it from the Interface Builder. Here is how to get a UIImage of your icon-gun@2x.png:

```
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
            pathForResource: @"icon-gun@2x" ofType:@"png"];     
    UIImage *imgGun2x = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```